# Unity Google Play License Verification (LVL)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play, android-lvl

I am trying to implement License verification into my android unity game. I found [this plugin](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/GooglePlayLicenseVerification), but the problem is that I am doing this for the first time and don't really know what to do.

I imported that into my project and attached [CheckLVLButton.cs](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/GooglePlayLicenseVerification/blob/master/Assets/Google%20Play%20License%20Verification/LVL_Example/CheckLVLButton.cs)
to a gameObject in my scene and inserted my public LVL key to the script.

I have even recompiled the Java source and attached the new classes_jar.txt to the CheckLVLButton script, but I am still getting this error. [This is the output of the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwtGf.png)

And when I try to debug it on Android using Visual Studio, there is an error that ServiceBinder is null.

But when I try to run the game and push that button it just says Invalid LVL key! Check the source... But I have it right.

Do I have to do something else?
Do I have to install it from google play beta test instead of building apk with unity and installing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it up in a test track, install it from the Playstore, and then test it. (it's a pain, and I am still not there yet.)
The reason that it is saying that it is invalid is because it's not installed from the playstore.

Comment: I could not figure it out, so I downloaded google play license library and build a unity android module in android studio. Which worked well.

Comment: @Jakub - I figured out part of my own issue - Unity was stripping out the .so file during the build process. I determined that by looking at the errors in the Unity Dev Console.  At the moment, I am looking for the Link.XML code to put in, to prevent the stripping.

Comment: @Michieal : did you solve the issue ? Can you update your response for others with the same issue?

Comment: @dimib : Yes - you put the apk in an Internal Test Track, and make yourself a tester. Then, you install the apk through the playstore, and test it. It's a serious pain.
As to the Link.XML code, I didn't find that. What I did was tell Unity to not strip binaries.